# Utility to create word list from a document

Tags: text-processing, parser

I need a utility that would parse a document (.odt or .txt), creating a list of words used therein, preferably ignoring the most common words (a, the, of, etc.).

A bonus would be if it gave a count of instances of each word, too, so that the report it generated would be something like:

```
Ammonia 1,
Animal, 5
Arkansas, 3
Attention, 4
Back, 7
... (etc.)
```

The "holy grail" for me would be if the utility also allowed you to compare two of the lists generated after parsing text, and then generated another report showing which words appeared in List A but not in List B, and vice versa. IOW, something like:

List A contains the following words that are not in List B:

```
Duckbilled
Platypus
. . . (etc.)
```

List B contains the following words that are not in List A:

```
Cameleopard
Ornithorynchus
Pteradactyl
. . . (etc.)
```

Does anybody know of such a utility or, if there are multiple of them, which one they consider of most value?